# Best way to display and edit an Excel workbook on a web page

Tags: .net, angular, aspose, excellibrary, spreadjs

Purpose - I want to display an excel workbook (Macro) on a web-page in Angular 2-4 project.

In an angular application I want to allow use to see an Excel workbook (Macro) data, and user must have the ability to edit it on the web page it self.

This Macro consists of huge data, on an average consider 50,000 (10 sheets in one workbook, each sheet containing 5000 data cells filled) cells Data.

I have tried several 3rd party libraries like "Aspose, SpreadJS, EP Plus" to get the desired result and got succeeded too, but the time these libraries are taking to load the Excel workbook is not acceptable. It usually takes 4-5 minutes to load the workbook.

So I just want to know if there is any tool / library which can do this in user acceptable time frame(i.e. 4-5- seconds).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aspose.Cells for GridWeb that will enable you to load Excel workbook and edit it on web page. GridWeb is Web Control that is available in C# or ASP.NET and Java or JSP. You can find their documentation online on Aspose Website and GridWeb examples can also be found on GitHub. GridWeb is capable of loading large Excel file which may contain Macros asynchronously and when paging is enabled. Please note, GridWeb cannot execute Macros inside your workbook and it can also not be used in Angular JS project.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*